# Ты мне ужасно нравишься!

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Насколько допустима эта фраза? "Ужасно" выступает в значении "очень".

Comment: Смотря с чем сравнивать. Если с употреблением "на сколько" в значении "насколько", тогда во много раз более допустима :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово "ужасно" в значении "очень" употребляется очень широко в разговорной речи.

У Толстого в "Войне и мире" находим:

> — Всё не то, что мать, — сказала графиня Марья, — я чувствую, что не то, и меня это мучит. Чудный мальчик; но я **ужасно** боюсь за него. Ему полезно будет общество.
>
> — Помню, — сказал Николай. — Я помню, что я к тебе пришел потом и мне хотелось тебя утешить и, знаешь, совестно было. **Ужасно** мы смешные были.

В Нацкорпусе 97 вхождений типа "ужасно нравиться".